# Lily species identifiaction and bloom time

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

Guys I want to know what species these lilies are and when do they bloom.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays the *Peace lilies* sold commercially are forced to bloom. They use **gibberellic acid** which will make the plants bloom within 3-4 months, when they will sell it.

> They are forced to bloom with gibberellic acid, a natural plant hormone that stimulates cell division and elongation.

So if you have bought a *Peace lily* that was in bloom, it does not mean that you will be able to get it bloom again very soon. Usually you would have to wait until the plant becomes mature. Even if you give it the perfect conditions you might have to wait for years.

> The plants used to be raised to maturity and natural flowering before the appearance of gibberellic acid. The process could take up to a year before there are sellable plants. Your plant is usually not mature when it comes from a commercial grower today. That means it is not old enough to flower naturally.

Read more at Gardening Know How: [Peace Lily Not Blooming: Reasons A Peace Lily Never Flowers](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/peace-lily/peace-lily-blooming.htm).

As some of the plants in your pot seems to be quite big thus probably mature, you will probably get flowers with the right conditions referred in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually a Lilium species - it has the common name of Peace Lily, but its botanical name is *Spathiphyllum*. The white bracts showing in the picture are part of the flower, and flowers are produced if the plant is happy in its environment, particularly between spring up to fall. They are a tropical, evergreen plant found growing on forest floors - which means they don't appreciate direct sunlight, but do need good daylight to produce flowers; care and growing instructions here:
[Growing Peace Lilies
How to Care for Peace Lilies (Spathiphyllum)](https://www.almanac.com/plant/peace-lilies).